# how to create relationships in loop in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create friend relationship to all the ids in the list but I am getting an error:

```
Node  already exists with label User and property "id"=[2]
 Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintViolation
```

Basically these ids already exist and I just want to create friend relationship to multiple ids at once using for-each.How can I achieve this or is there any other way to do the same? I really appreciate any help.

```
MATCH (u:User {id:"3"})
FOREACH (id in ["2","4","5"] |
  MERGE (u)-[:FRIEND]->(:User {id:id}))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the usage of MERGE. Merge needs you to bind both ends of the relationship if you don't want either node recreated in the absence of the pattern existing between them.
u is bound, but because there is no FRIEND relation from u to the other users, the entire pattern is created from u, with the FRIEND relation and a new User node.

You can't MATCH the user in FOREACH so instead, use

```
MATCH (u:User {id:"3"})
match (fb:User) 
where fb.id in ["2","4","5"] 
MERGE (u)-[:FRIEND]->(fb)
```

Comment: How can I create new ids the same way if those ids are not on my db?

Comment: If you want to either create or match the ids, this should work:
MATCH (u:User {id:"3"})
unwind ["2","4","5"] as fbid
merge (fb:User {id:fbid})
MERGE (u)-[:FRIEND]->(fb)

Comment: Please take a look at this.Thanks in Advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208963/how-to-create-relationship-and-merge-create-new-node-in-loop-in-neo4j

Answer (score 2):

As the users already exist, there is a more simple way :

```
MATCH (u:User {id:"3"})
MATCH (friends:User) WHERE friends.id IN ["2","4","5"]
MERGE (u)-[:FRIEND]->(friends)
```

Comment: PLease take a look at this .Thanks in Advance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208963/how-to-create-relationship-and-merge-create-new-node-in-loop-in-neo4j