# how to create relationship and merge/create new node in loop in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create friend relationship to all the ids in the list but I am getting an error:

```
y already declared (line 2, column 41 (offset: 64))

"Merge (y:User{id:"21",name:"b"})
 Merge (y:User{id:"41",name:"d"})
 Merge (y:User{id:"51",name:"e"}) "
                                         ^
 Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax
```

I am trying to create a new user with id,name,year and also relationship with existing node at the same time .How can I do it ?Is there any other way also?I really appreciate any help.

```
MATCH (u:User {id:"2"})
Merge (y:User{id:"21",name:"b",year:"2010"})
Merge (y:User{id:"41",name:"d",year:"2011"})
Merge (y:User{id:"51",name:"e",,year:"2013"}) 
MERGE (u)-[:FRIEND]->(y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reusing identifier y won't work.

Try

```
MATCH (u:User {id:"2"})
unwind [{id:"21",name:"b",year:"2010"},
        {id:"41",name:"d",year:"2011"},
        {id:"51",name:"e",year:"2013"}] as user
merge (y:User {id: user.id, name: user.name,year:user.year})
MERGE (u)-[:FRIEND]->(y)
```

Comment: Can you please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217665/create-relationship-and-merge-node-in-loop-in-neo4j .Thanks a ton.Stuck with it for a long time.Thanks again.