# create relationship and merge node in loop in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a relationship in loop from both top list and bottom list .I am trying to connect the top loop with the bottom loop .I really appreciate any help.Thanks.

```
 UNWIND [{id:"1",name:"b1",year:"2010"},
         {id:"2",name:"d1",year:"2011"},
         {id:"3",name:"e1",year:"2013"}] as user
 MERGE (u:User {id: user.id, name: user.name,year:user.year})
 UNWIND [{id:"21",name:"b",year:"2010"},
         {id:"41",name:"d",year:"2011"},
         {id:"51",name:"e",year:"2013"}] as w
 MERGE (y:W {id: w.id, name: w.name,year:w.year})
 MERGE (u)-[:SHARE]->(y)
```

Error:

```
WITH is required between MERGE and UNWIND (line 8, column 1 (offset: 192))
"unwind [{id:"21",name:"b",year:"2010"},"
 ^
 Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to connect all of the `User` nodes to all of the `W` nodes then you could just switch the first `MERGE` and the second `UNWIND`:

```
UNWIND [{id:"1",name:"b1",year:"2010"},
        {id:"2",name:"d1",year:"2011"},
        {id:"3",name:"e1",year:"2013"}] as user
UNWIND [{id:"21",name:"b",year:"2010"},
        {id:"41",name:"d",year:"2011"},
        {id:"51",name:"e",year:"2013"}] as w
MERGE (u:User {id: user.id, name: user.name,year:user.year})
MERGE (y:W {id: w.id, name: w.name,year:w.year})
MERGE (u)-[:SHARE]->(y)
```

Comment: I am sorry.I want the first item in top row to merge with the first item in bottom row and so on.In the above example all are merged.How can I do sequence merge in single query?Thanks again. Also is it possible to merge with 2 instead of 1 in some cases?

Comment: Basically I am trying to connect existing node to new nodes .But each time existing node and new nodes are different.like user 1-> w1 then user2-> w2 where user exists but not w.How can I do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you generating these queries programmatically?  You might be better off just generating `MERGE` statements like `MERGE (u:User {id: "1", name: "b1", year: "2010"})-[:SHARE]->(y:W {id: "21", name: "b", year: "2010"})`

Comment: If you specify a `MERGE` statement like that it will create both the nodes and the relationships all at once.  Also, I'm not sure I completely understand, but you might want to only specify one or two properties for the nodes (like the `id` property) and then use `ON CREATE SET` to set the rest so that you don't end up with duplicate nodes

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do, but I have to agree with @Brian that you'd be better off programmatically generating the statements as per his comment.

```
WITH  [{id:"1",name:"b1",year:"2010"},
         {id:"2",name:"d1",year:"2011"},
         {id:"3",name:"e1",year:"2013"}] as user,
[{id:"21",name:"b",year:"2010"},
         {id:"41",name:"d",year:"2011"},
         {id:"51",name:"e",year:"2013"}] as w
foreach (i in range(0,length(user)-1) | 
MERGE (u:User {id: (user[i]).id, name: (user[i]).name,year:(user[i]).year})
MERGE (y:W {id: (w[i]).id, name: (w[i]).name,year:(w[i]).year})
MERGE (u)-[:SHARE]->(y))
```

Comment: Please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349125/get-difference-between-2-field-values-for-2-different-users-in-neo4j.Thanks