# get difference between field values and sum in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I get difference between 2 fields: r.rating_val and rw.rating_val and  sum of these fields using neo4j query?I really appreciate any help.

```
MATCH (a:user{id:"1"})-[r:`rating`]->(b),
 (w:user{id:"3"})-[rw:`rating`]->(b)
RETURN DISTINCT b,r.rating_val ,rw.rating_val
```

Comment: When you write `id`, is that the internal ID or your own ID property?

Comment: query looks ok if you really mean the same `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract/add them in the return clause

```
MATCH (a:user{id:"1"})-[r:`rating`]->(b),
 (w:user{id:"3"})-[rw:`rating`]->(b)
RETURN DISTINCT b,
r.rating_val-rw.rating_val as difference,
r.rating_val+rw.rating_val as sum
```

Comment: I am getting Don't know how to Subtract(Property(r,rating_val(11)),Property(rw,rating_val(11))) `1` with `3`

Comment: What's the data type of rating_val? Do you have a small set of cypher statements to set up a graph? Or alternatively create one at http://console.neo4j.org/?init=0

Comment: Cool I tried toInt(rating_val) and it worked .Thanks again.Thanks a ton.

Comment: Please look into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353205/top-10-users-for-each-game-in-neo4j-based-of-games-they-like .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [abs()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/mathematical/numeric/#functions-abs) function for difference.

```
    MATCH (a:user{id:"1"})-[r:`rating`]->(b),
     (w:user{id:"3"})-[rw:`rating`]->(b)
    RETURN DISTINCT b,
     abs(r.rating_val - rw.rating_val) as difference,
     (r.rating_val + rw.rating_val) as sum
```