# top 10 users for each game in neo4j based of games they like

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get top 10 users who have liked particular game with game_id from 1 to 25.
These games have a relationship with user called rating with property rating_val=1 to 10 .

How to get 25 rows with group of all users who have rating_val from 1 to 10  desc order for each game category.

Basically :
25 game categories with id 1 to 25
games_like is a relationship with with rating_val from 1-10
users are nodes with id,name

This query is not working:

```
MATCH (u:user { user_id:"1" })
MATCH (o:user)
WHERE o <> u 
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:games_like]->(d)<-[rw:games_like]-(o)
RETURN
  toInt(r.rating_val)+toInt(rw.rating_val) as sum ,
  collect(DISTINCT (r.rating_val)) AS user1,
  collect(DISTINCT (rw.rating_val)) AS user2,
  d
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused because your description seems to be saying you just want a join between users and games, but your query is matching two users against one game.  Also, do your game nodes have a label?

From your description, this is the query I would write:

```
MATCH (game)<-[rel:games_like]-(user:user)
WITH game, user ORDER BY rel.rating_val DESC
RETURN game, collect(user)[0..10]
```

That returns you the top users for each game.  If you want to limit it you could do:

```
MATCH (game)<-[rel:games_like]-(user:user)
WHERE
  1 <= game.game_id AND game.game_id <= 25 AND
  1 <= rel.rating_val AND rel.rating_val <= 10
WITH game, user ORDER BY rel.rating_val DESC
RETURN game, collect(user)[0..10]
```

Comment: Hi Brian.I have updated the Q again.The query above is not working .How can I grt 25 rows with group of all users who have rating_val from 1 to 10 in desc  order for each game category.

Comment: How about a small dataset on http://console.neo4j.org/?init=0 or as a set of cypher statements along with what you expect from the query?

Comment: Agreed, I'm having trouble understanding your model and what you'd like